# Does 'which' refer to the noun immediately preceding it?

Tags: word-order, ambiguity

Is the 'which' in

> Proposition 25 suggests a better definition of m-reducibility than given in Definition 23, which is also the one typically given in texts

ambiguous? It is a line from an article I've written, and the anonymous referee claims that

> the reader has to guess to which of the two definitions the "which" at the beginning of the line refers.

It seems to me, however, that the which should refer to the definition immediately preceding it, since if I'd wanted it to refer to the other, I'd have written something like

> Proposition 25 suggests a better definition of m-reducibility, which is also the one typically given in texts, than given in Definition 23.

As the title indicates, this is essentially a question about whether 'which' by default refers to the noun closest to it.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the tags on this site. I tried to find the most appropriate ones, but re-tagging would be most appreciated.

Comment: It does not. And it's not _which_ that decides it. You're asking about what noun phrase a relative clause modifies. Normally it's the one immediately before it. But this leads to [attachment ambiguities](http://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/ambiguity.html).

Comment: @JohnLawler Okay thanks. In the example I provided, do you agree with the referee?

Comment: @Quinn: Your referee is at best nit-picking, but realistically I'd say he's just plain ***wrong***. The general principle is as John says, and your example isn't a situation where one could make a credible case for overriding it.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: Yes, I agree with the referee. For a scientific or math journal, ambiguity in presentation is taboo. It may not make a whole lot of difference, but confusing a reader for any reason detracts from the attention you want them to pay to the arguments in the paper. If you confuse them about irrelevancies, they'll never get to the arguments; or if they do, they won't trust your presentation as much.

Comment: What John Lawler says. The Adamantine Rule of Written English: *Anything which **can** be misunderstood **will** be*.

Comment: Especially if there's profit to be made.

Answer (score 1):

It technically is ambiguous, even though I think most people would read it as intended, I suppose the fact is that you could have meant something different and someone could have interpreted differently, means it really is ambiguous.

Would it not remove ambiguity to simply remove ", which" and replace with "and":

"Proposition 25 suggests a better definition of m-reducibility than given in Definition 23 and is also the one typically given in texts".

That removes the ambiguity for me at least!

Comment: It seems adding the "and" gives the opposite meaning I intended. It is Definition 23 that is typically given in texts, not Proposition 25. So I guess it must indeed be quite ambiguous!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not happy about

> Proposition 25 suggests a better definition of m-reducibility than
>   given in Definition 23

itself, preferring a *that* or an *is* before *given*.

I feel this should be changed before deciding on which noun is being modified.

Comment: Yes, I considered that too. But does that have any bearing on the ambiguity of the 'which'?

Comment: Yes - the missing pronoun is one of the candidates! Though the rephrasing should probably be 'than that given _as_ Definition 23'.

Answer (score 0):

Proposition 25 suggests a better definition of m-reducibility, which is also the one typically given in texts, than given in Definition 23.

In this sentence which can refer to 'definition' but not to 'preposition 25'. Why ? There should be no verb between which and the noun that which is supposed to modify.

There is no such rule that which has to modify the noun adjacent to it. Which can jump over 'of m-reducibility' to refer to 'definition' as long as the text in between is  giving additional information about 'definition'
.