# Clause applying to first part of sentence when 'and' is used?

Tags: conjunctions, antecedents

> The requirement referred to in the first subparagraph shall not apply to fund of funds structures and master-feeder structures where the underlying funds have a depositary which provides ownership verification and record-keeping functions for this fund’s assets.

In this sentence, does the clause "where the underlying funds have a depositary which provides ownership verification and record-keeping functions for this fund’s assets" also apply to "fund of funds structures" (before the *and*)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does 'which' refer to the noun immediately preceding it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116646/does-which-refer-to-the-noun-immediately-preceding-it), where [John Lawler comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116646/does-which-refer-to-the-noun-immediately-preceding-it#comment237833_116646) that such structures *can lead to attachment ambiguities*.

Comment: It is ambiguous, and for a small fee any lawyer will argue whichever way you prefer. In fact, forget the lawyers and the lunar lander. For a small fee *I* will argue whichever way you prefer.

Comment: FumbleFingers, the use of which is not the question here, it whether the clause is applicable to master-feeder structures only or master-feeder and fund of funds.

Comment: With a (an Oxford) comma before *and master-feeder ...,* the qualifier clause *where ...* applies only to the *master-feeder structures.* With a comma before the qualifier clause *where ...* itself, it applies to both. With no comma it's ambiguous, in fact, poor drafting.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either. The lack of a comma before "and" suggests the clause refers to both.

Getting the correct meaning here requires subject knowledge, not just grammar parsing. You would have to know about this subject and make an informed decision whether "fund of funds structures" could have "underlying funds" that have a "depositary that provides ownership verification and record-keeping functions" for these funds' assets.

But there is another issue. "Which" should really be used only in non-restrictive clauses, and then always preceded by a comma. In this sentence, there appears to be a restrictive clause, so it should begin with "that."

Comment: This 'rule' about ***which*** only being used in on-restrictive clauses has been being ridiculed for eons by grammarians. It just isn't true at all and never has been. However, it does not stop the myth being promulgated, unfortunately...

Comment: B.S. It's established AP style and cited in many writing guides. And useful, too.

Comment: "Eons" huh? Hyperbole much?

Comment: If you want your intended reader to get your comment you need to put @name before their comment in order to 'ping' them.

Comment: Yes, the style guide of the AP is for journalists and aims to prevent Journos being subject to complaints by morons.  Perhaps these links might help. Notice the title of the top article there: [Language log: Zwicky, Pullum](http://arnoldzwicky.org/2011/10/23/whichthat/)

Answer (score 0):

As given, it is ambiguous. If this is your text, I would suggest rewriting it to either:

> The requirement referred to in the first subparagraph shall not apply to fund of funds structures**, or to** master-feeder structures where the underlying funds have a depositary which provides ownership verification and record-keeping functions for this fund’s assets.

which applies the latter clause to master-feeder structures but not to fund structures, or:

> The requirement referred to in the first subparagraph shall not apply to **those** fund of funds structures and master-feeder structures **in which** the underlying funds have a depositary which provides ownership verification and record-keeping functions for this fund’s assets.

...which applies it to both.

If it's not your text, and you're trying to decipher what someone else has written, I'm afraid you'll have to figure it out from context, if possible. If I were forced to choose an interpretation at gunpoint, I would guess that the clause applies to master-feeder structures, but not to fund of fund structures. But it could so easily go the other way.